# Bibliographie in latex beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, bibtex

How can I write the beamer bibliography ?

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}
\bibliography{../bib_files/jabrefmaster.bib}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) In your future questions, please try to add a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) of what you are trying to do for people to be able to reproduce the problem you get and to further help you. However, here, start by removing the `.bib` extension in your `\bibliography` command.